# Amarok in KDE and Banshee in gnome

Tags: banshee, kde

I want to do something to prevent Banshee from start in KDE (even accidentally)

**Edit:** I want to do somehow lock the banshee in KDE. (`/bin/banshee` be only valid in gnome.)

Comment: do you mean that you don't want to see Banshee icon in KDE or does it somehow behave in KDE?

Comment: @shookees: No. I don't care about visibility. I want to do something to prevent banshee from start in KDE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To hide banshee from the menu's in KDE you'll need to change the desktop file to only show the menu item in Unity/Gnome

```
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/applications
cp /usr/share/applications/banshee.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
```

Edit the file `~/.local/share/applications/banshee.desktop`

Add to the bottom of this file

```
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
```

Save.

However the above only hides banshee.  To prevent banshee from starting in KDE you'll need to edit the banshee executable script

```
sudo nano /usr/bin/banshee
```

now add the following at the position shown:

```
if [ x"$KDE_FULL_SESSION" = x"true" ]; then
  exit
fi
```

[image]